# Error with installing "rand 0.8.3" through cargo

Tags: rust, fedora, rust-cargo, toml

I'm having an issue where Cargo refuses to build rand 0.8.3, I get this error message about a misplaced ":"

I'm very new to rust and cargo so this may be a very simple question and it's based off following the rust language tutorial listed on the official rust website

What have I done wrong?

I'm on Fedora 36 in case it helps

```
Does $LD_LIBRARY_PATH have an unterminated quote character?

Caused by:
  failed to join path array: ["/home/my_name/Documents/Rust/Rust Learning/2: Programming a Guessing Game/target/debug/deps", "/home/my_name/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib", "/home/ru/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib"]

Caused by:
  path segment contains separator `:`
```

Comment: You have a folder named `2: Programming a Guessing Game`. Try removing the `:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May have something to do with the colon in the path: https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/3736

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).